# Undefined variable with forelse loop in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, for-loop, variables, undefined, laravel-blade

I get this error on the @forelse($services...) line:

> Undefined variable: services (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\resources\views\services.blade.php)

The error : https://easyupload.io/yrmnnf)

I'm following the Coder's pick Laravel 6 tut series on youtube and more people seem to have this issue.
I've checked the code 50 times and it's identical to the youtubevideo.
Here is my services.blade.php:

```
@extends('app')

@section('title', 'Services')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcome to Laravel 6 from Services</h1>

    <ul>
        @forelse($services as $service)
            <li>{{ $service }}</li>
        @empty
            <li>No services available.</li>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Here is the controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HelloController extends Controller {
    public function about() {
        return view('about');
    }

    public function services() {
        $services = [
            'Cool Service',
            'Another Cool Service',
        ];

        return view('services', compact('services'));
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Another Cool Service,` is missing a closing `'`

Comment: I had it in my code but not on here, thanks.

Comment: No because I had moved on in the tutorial so this is the code from an earlier episode that I just now wrote from the video to stackoverflow. But it was very minor changes, in fact i copy pasted it now so the code is the same, editor and SO.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this code, or I'm blind. There has to be something else that you did not pasted here, maybe in routes web.php you are actually pointing to another controller or function without controller? Show us routes, or even better - put whole project on Git or codesandbox.

Comment: Hm, that's totally fine code, works as expected here (Linux, Laravel Framework 7.9.2). Do you `@include` services.blade.php somewhere else? You could try to `php artisan view:clear`. How do you call that controller@method, can you post your `app.blade.php` and your `routes/web.php`?

Comment: I uploaded on GitHub, first time doing so hope it's no problem :) https://github.com/cubesacube/project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes are wrong, you only show a view without using your controller, so `$services` is not set at all in `services.blade.php`.

Change

```
Route::view('/services', 'Services');
```

to

```
Route::get('services', 'HelloController@services');
```

in your `routes/web.php` file.

PS: You already have that route in your routes file, but the line is commented

Comment: That worked, thank you brother! The youtuber said that you can use Route::view, weird, do you know why it doesnt work, but with Route::view(about) it works?

Comment: You can use `Route::view(...)` to only show a view. This works for `Route::view(about)` because there are no variables in `about.blade.php`. Feel free to accept as answer when you can